# Pass custom parameters to a dart application when using pub serve to run it

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Is it possible to pass some argument to a dart application when running it using `pub serve`? What I'm trying to do is have an application use some mocked services while I'm developing it, but then when it's deployed I'd like to replace mocked services with real ones. For example:

```dart
const bool DEBUG = true;

class AppModule extends Module {
  AppModule() {
    type(PaymentService, implementedBy: DEBUG ? PaypalPaymentService : MockPaymentService );
  }
}
```

I'd like this DEBUG parameter to somehow come form the environment and to be easily configurable when running the application using `pub serve`. Which is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the URL. If `host` is `127.0.0.1` your in the development environment, otherwise it's prod.

Another idea is to use a transformer that injects something when `mode` is `debug`.
Not sure if that is really possible this way.

```
$ pub help serve
Run a local web development server.

Usage: pub serve
-h, --help               Print usage information for this command.
    --port               The port to listen on.
                         (defaults to "8080")

    --[no-]dart2js       Compile Dart to JavaScript.
                         (defaults to on)

    --[no-]force-poll    Force the use of a polling filesystem watcher.
    --mode               Mode to run transformers in.
                         (defaults to "debug")
```

Comment: URL won't work as I could be running the application in the mode where real services are used even on localhost. Transformers might work but I can't find an example of how to write one. Any pointers? The documentation on pub does not show how to write one, only how to use it.

Comment: There was a discussion recently that a documentation should be written how to build a transformer but haven't seen one yet. (https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/d4jrnPzFV2w)

Comment: Also when I run pub serve how would I specify if this is a 'production' mode or 'debug'? I was looking for something like `pub serve --mode=debug`.

Comment: I added the output from `pub help serve` to my answer. `--mode=debug` is default.

Comment: Oh... sorry, I didn't realize that pub already has a flag named 'mode'. I was looking for passing a custom flag (coincidentally I used the name mode which is already exists). Maybe a better example would be `pub serve --app_mode=debug'. I'm thinking of setting a meta tag in html and then reading that to set the mode... Then I could use transformer to actually change the value, during deploy process, if needed....

Comment: I find the existing `mode` parameter convenient as it defaults to `debug` for `pub serve` and `release` for `pub build` so you don't have to bother setting a value. But of course in your use case other options may fit better.