# Dart: How to use different settings in debug and production mode?

Tags: dart

Are there any ideas how I can setup my Dart app to use different settings in debug mode (running in Dartium) and production mode?

For example, I'm using PouchDb in my app, that replicates the database to a particular CouchDb instance, given by an url: `db.replicateTo(url);`
In debug mode, I would like to use another CouchDb instance (another url) than in production mode.

So, are there any ideas or approaches, to use different setups in both modes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this works since a short while:

```yaml
transformers: # or dev_transformers
- $dart2js:
  environment: { PROD: "true" }
```

access it from the code like

```dart
String.fromEnvironment()

main() {
  print('PROD: ${const String.fromEnvironment('PROD')}'); 
  // works in the browser
  // prints 'PROD: null' in Dartium
  // prints 'PROD: true' in Chrome
}
```

see also

- [Configuring the Built-in dart2js Transformer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html)
- [How to achieve precompiler directive like functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338688)
- https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/798
- http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/12/compile-time-dead-code-elimination-with.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.0/dart-core/bool/bool.fromEnvironment.html
- [dart check if is building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487428/dart-check-if-is-building)