# dart check if is building

Tags: dart, dart2js

I would like to skip some specific code on pub build.

example:

Log.print('something ${StackTrace.current}');

I would like that the code above was not transpilled to JS in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asserts are only executed in checked mode and won't be included by `pub build` in production mode by default:

```
assert(() {
  Log.print('something ${StackTrace.current}');
  return true;
})
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1dc717da03b078504a19e6bc7a05aae3) doesn't print it because it builds in production mode.

You can also pass "environment" (not mix up with OS environment variables) to `pub build` and read it in code

```
transformers: # or dev_transformers
- $dart2js:
  environment: { PROD: "true" }
```

```
const prod = String.fromEnvironment('PROD')
print('PROD: $prod');
// prints 'PROD: null' in Dartium
// prints 'PROD: true' in Chrome
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22524258/217408

Comment: For curiosity: If I put the entire Log.print function within an assert, the calls for the function will also be removed by the tree shaking?

Comment: Yes. It should also be removed if you leave it outside of `assert(...)` and only call it from inside. If it's not used from anywhere, tree-shaking should remove it, also if it's used from code that doesn't make it into the build output like the one from within `assert(...)`.

Comment: See [Compile-time dead code elimination with dart2js](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/12/compile-time-dead-code-elimination-with.html) and [bool.fromEnvironment doc](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.0/dart-core/bool/bool.fromEnvironment.html) for more infos