# Does Flutter remove debug-mode code when compiling for release?

Tags: debugging, dart, flutter, assert, production

I'm wondering whether it is safe to place passwords directly in the Dart code like below. Does Flutter remove the code when compiling it for release? Of course I want to make sure that the code cannot be decompiled such that the username and password can be extracted.

```
bool get isInDebugMode {
  bool inDebugMode = false;
  assert(inDebugMode = true);
  return inDebugMode;
}

if(inDebugMode){
  emailController.text = 'random@email.com';
  passwordController.text = 'secret';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The code you provided won't be tree-shaked. As `isInDebugMode` isn't a constant.

Instead you can use an `assert` this way:

```
assert(() {
  emailController.text = 'random@email.com';
  passwordController.text = 'secret';
  return true;
}());
```

Answer (score 4):

Tree-shaking removes that code when `inDebugMode` is a const value.

"safe" is a strong word for that though even when tree-shaking removes the code.
You could make a mistake that causes tree-shaking to retain the code.
You probably commit the code to a CVS repo.
...

You can use

- a const value

```
const bool isProduction = bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product');
if(isProduction) {
  ...
}
```

- different `lib/main.dart` files with `flutter run -t lib/debug_main.dart`
- or the assert method as mentioned (see also [How to exclude debug code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208213/how-to-exclude-debug-code/24208259#24208259))

Comment: Which means no here