# switching between debugging and production mode

Tags: dart, flutter

As a fast way of debugging app while developing is writing a statement like:

```
print($data)
```

is there is a way to stop printing when switching to production mode so it will not affect the performance of the app?

a boolean as a switch for example?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `debugPrint` instead of `print` for dev only logging

```
debugPrint(data)
```

`debugPrint` implementation can be made to change between environment. For instance in your main you can do:

```
void main() {
  bool isInRelease = true;

  assert(() { isInRelease = false; return true; }());

  if (isInRelease) {
    debugPrint = (String? message, { int? wrapWidth }) {};
  }
}
```

This will replace the implementation of `debugPrint` with something that does nothing in release

Comment: oh okay .. i should run it in the release mode

Comment: this should use kReleaseMode  instead of asserts ... https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kReleaseMode-constant.html

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html would allow this. 
The docs don't tell if it prints in production mode, but you could run different `main()` that assigns a no-op function to `debugPrint`.

Another way would be to use [How do I build different versions of my Flutter app for qa/dev/prod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438564/how-do-i-build-different-versions-of-my-flutter-app-for-qa-dev-prod/52820431#52820431) or the assert trick [Does Flutter remove debug-mode code when compiling for release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225385/does-flutter-remove-debug-mode-code-when-compiling-for-release/53225400#53225400) to override `debugPrint`

Comment: I guess I got a second faster :p

Comment: Looks like it :D