# Flutter - change project from production to development

Tags: flutter, dart

I have cloned a project from github, it is working perfectly fine. The two issues I have is -

1. Whenever I put a print statement it warns me saying - **Avoid Print calls in production code**
2. The second one, it warns me about adding const to widgets. Why would I need to append **const** to widgets? I know there is avoid statement that you can put in on top to get rid of these warnings, but I would like to know why there is a warning. Example below -

   ```
   children: [
      const Text('Sign in with your phone number below'),
      const SizedBox(height: 18),
   ]
   ```

Could someone explain how to change this project from release mode to debug mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - instead of print statement put 'debugPrint(data)'. more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240901/switching-between-debugging-and-production-mode).
2 - const improves performance a bit and enhances the work need to be done by the garbage collector.

for more information you can reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492705/does-using-const-in-the-widget-tree-improve-performance).

Comment: Thanks Benyamin. this is new info for me.