# How to make pub build show warnings/hints from all packages

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have an app that has about 10 packages that I developed myself. I only run pub build on one of them and it is dependent on the other packages. When I run pub build I receive output like:

```
[Dart2JS on myapp_client|web/index.html_bootstrap.dart]:
3 warning(s) suppressed in package:myapp_shared.
[Warning from Dart2JS on myapp_client|web/index.html_bootstrap.dart]:
4 hint(s) suppressed in package:myapp_infra.
[Dart2JS on myapp_client|web/index.html_bootstrap.dart]:
8 warning(s) suppressed in package:myapp_client.
```

Since these warnings all come from my code I am interested in seeing the full warnings, I do *not* want them to be suppressed. How can I do this? I've seen that dart2js has a --show-package-warnings option but pub build does not have this. Also this option is not configurable in pubspec.yaml on the dart2js transformer.

Comment: Why do you think this is not possible to configure for the `dart2js` transformer? Amiga forever ;-)

Comment: In pubspec.yaml, transformers, $dart2js, I tried putting show-package-warnings: true. Pub build reported it was an invalid option. It is only documented as being available on the command-line so I was just trying. Yes, Amiga forever :-)

Comment: You could try `commandLineOptions` like shown in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21339347/217408 (it's a while I tried it). See also https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html at the bottom of the page.

Comment: One option is to manually run "dartanalyzer --package-warnings" from the command line. https://www.dartlang.org/tools/analyzer/

Comment: commandLineOptions worked! :-) I added this to the pubspec.yaml under $dart2js "commandLineOptions: [--show-package-warnings]". Now when I do pub build I get to see all the warnings from my packages. I guess I will also see warnings from other packages if there are any so the solution might not be ideal but it works for me since no other packages I depend on has warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems no such option is available.
With http://dartbug.com/9512 generating warnings for dependencies were suppressed but no exception for path dependencies (see codereview link in the linked issue).

Comment: I have submitted a new bug to see warnings originating from file-referenced packages. https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21651

Answer (score 3):

Günter and Jonas have kinda answered the question. Since it took me a few minutes to figure out the actual syntax I'd like to make it clear. Your `pubspec.yaml` should include the following lines:

```
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--show-package-warnings]
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, these lines should be under the transformers: section